# Is there a way to make the loading() void begin before the main() function?

Tags: c

I am very new to C and I am trying to create a sort of loading screen that appears before the actual program runs. I compiled it and it ran perfectly once but after that one time it wont do it anymore. I am wondering if I messed something up? The reason I dont want it in the main function is because I want to allow for returning to the main menu without having to input a name again. Any help would be amazing, like I said I am very new to C. P.S. I can attach the header file if needed. I am not sure what the issue is.

Main file:

```
#include "periodic-header.h"

void blue() {
    printf("\033[0;36m");
}
void lime() {
    printf("\033[1;32m");
}
void yellow() {
    printf("\033[1;33m");
}
void colorReset() {
    printf("\033[0m");
}

loading();

int main(char *userName) {
    int choice;
    
    colorReset();   
    system("cls");
    table();
    printf("\n\n");

yellow();
printf("\t\t   Using the numbers on your keyboard,\n");
printf("\t\t   Please select an option:\n\n");
printf("\t\t   1) Examine element\n");
printf("\t\t   2) Input data for element\n");
printf("\t\t   3) Exit program\n");
    choose(&choice,3);
    switch(choice){
        case 1:{
        examineElement();
        break;
        }
        case 2:{printf("\t\t   Test 2\n"); 
//      addElement();
        break;
        }
        case 3:{
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t   Thanks for stopping by %s,\n", userName);
        Sleep ( 300 );
        printf("\t\t   ... hope to see you again soon!\n");
        colorReset();
        exit(1);
        break;
        }
        default: printf("\t\t   Sorry %s, that is not a valid option", userName); break;
    }
colorReset();

}
```

Loading file:

```
#include "periodic-header.h"

void loading(){     
    system("cls");
    yellow();
    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t [ ASPECT ]\n");
    colorReset();
    blue();
    Sleep ( 10000 );
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Loading...\n");
    Sleep ( 900 );
    colorReset();
    yellow();
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("\t\t   Welcome...\n");
    Sleep ( 300 );
    printf("\t\t   Please enter your name: ");  
    char userName [20];
    fscanf(stdin, "%20s", userName);
    Sleep ( 1300 );
}
```

Header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


extern char userName[20];
// Prints view of periodic table
void table();
// Manipulates periodic table
void examineElement();
void addElement();
//Not in use yet
void menuSelection();
char selection[2];
// Used to choose what you want to do with the program
int choose();
// Element Credentials
extern char elementName[50];
extern char sb[5];
extern int atm;
extern float atms;
extern char block;
extern char atc[20];
extern char prop[250];
```

Comment: Not using standard C. But wy do you want that? Why not simply call it the first thing you do inside the `main` function?

Comment: Also note that `userName` inside the `loading` function is *different* from any possible `userName` variable in the glocal scope. And that you don't actually have a global definition of `userName` only a *declaration*. And `int main(char *userName)`? That's simply not how it works. It seems you have some misunderstandings about how C works, please take some time to refresh a beginners book to refresh on the basics.

Comment: Hi, I want it outside of main because once in the program I have an option to return to the main menu, which is `main()`. If I were to put it inside `main()` you would need to input your `userName` everytime you returned to the main menu. I feel like that could get annoying after a while

Comment: You should *never* call `main` yourself! (Even through it's allowed in C.) Instead you just `return` to the `main` function and use a *loop*.

Comment: Its a bad idea, but you can re-specify an entry point with `-e` linker option under `GCC 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's not possible, because `main()`, the entry point for the program, which means it's the function that gets executed when you run your program. However, what you can do is put the contents of main in a separate function and call `loading()` in main before your program begins. Here's what I'm referring to:

```
void load() {
    // loading screen
}
void program() {
    // the program
}
int main() {
    load();
    program();
}
```

Comment: would it be possible for me to make the loading screen the main and then make the main menu a void then?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Anyway your design is wrong. Read the second comment to your question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky actually, it is. Thanks to gcc's `-ffreestanding` parameter. But I do agree there's something wrong with his design and that he should be trying to do that.

Comment: @ShellCode yes, but that's not standard C

Answer (score 0):

We can make *any* function run before `main` is called *if* we make it a *constructor* function.

Constructors can take a "priority" number, so we can have several that are run in a specific order.

Lower priority numbers are reserved for `gcc/glibc` internal callback functions, so we should add a bias so we don't conflict with them.

Likewise, we can set up a "destructor" function.

---

Here's some sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ctors               ctorx(0)
#define dtors               dtorx(0)
#define ctorx(_prio)        __attribute__((constructor(_prio + 201)))
#define dtorx(_prio)        __attribute__((destructor(_prio + 201)))

void ctorx(0)
loading(void)
{
    printf("%s ...\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

void ctorx(-1)
i_am_called_before_loading(void)
{
    printf("%s ...\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

void ctorx(1)
i_am_called_after_loading(void)
{
    printf("%s ...\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

void dtorx(0)
i_am_called_after_main_has_completed(void)
{
    printf("%s ...\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

int
main(void)
{

    printf("main: running ...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the output of the program:

```
i_am_called_before_loading ...
loading ...
i_am_called_after_loading ...
main: running ...
i_am_called_after_main_has_completed ...
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Can you explain how to make constructors in C? My guess is your code will not work without a C++ compiler. – Brendan

No, this will work regardless.

This *is* part of `gcc`. See `info gcc` for more details.

AFAICT, this [directly] uses the [underlying] mechanism that `c++` would use for static/global constructors/destructors. That is, `c++` doesn't "own" the mechanism, but is merely a client of a more general mechanism that is made available by ELF and can be used by *various* different languages.

This has been added in the last few years.

Before that, one could use ELF's `.init/.fini` section attributes to store pointers to callback functions.

This is how shared libraries (`.so` files) get callbacks to [hidden] initialization functions. The ELF interpreter (e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so`) will find and issue the callbacks when loading the libraries.

Or, for really old code, the init/fini functions *had* to be called `init` and `fini`. For this, we *may* have had to put the functions into a separate shared library (`.so`) but, now, that is no longer the case.

AFAIK, the older mechanisms are still available/usable/valid and can be used in parallel to the `constructor` attribute.

I'm *not* sure how `gcc` implements the `constructor` attribute, but here's a *guess*:

The attribute gets morphed into a function pointer that gets put into (e.g.) `section(gcc_constructor_list)`. The `crt0.o` [or equivalent] routine will call things defined in that section.

Another way would be to generate pointers to the functions and use ELF's `.init/.fini` sections.

Or, the function that issues the calls to `gcc_constructor_list` could just be an ELF `.init` function (and, therefore, doesn't need to be in `crt0.o` at all).

To see what is actually generated, after building the program, we can do `readelf -a ./program` and in the output there are:

`.init` and `.fini` section header. Segment sections of `init_array` and `.fini_array`

And, some entries in the "dynamic section" for: `INIT_ARRAY`, `INIT_ARRAYSZ`, `FINI_ARRAY`, and `FINI_ARRAYSZ`

Comment: Can you explain how to make constructors in C? My guess is your code will not work without a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Brendan I've added an update to my answer

Comment: Thanks - your update definitely improves the answer (makes it clear that it's not standard C, but relies on a mixed-language franken-beast that allowed a features of completely different languages to hemorrhage everywhere and surface as implementation defined hackery).

Comment: @Brendan Whoosh! The .init/.fini stuff has been around for decades. Your comment says that you've got a lot more to learn about how shared libraries actually work. See: http://beefchunk.com/documentation/sys-programming/binary_formats/elf/elf_from_the_programmers_perspective/node3.html _If a function is placed in the .init section, the system will execute it before the main function. Also the functions placed in the .fini section will be executed by the system after the main function returns. **This feature is utilized by compilers to implement global constructors and destructors in C++**_

Comment: Heh. Your comment says that you don't even know the difference between the C standard and "implementation defined". You're abusing something that isn't even a standard attribute for C++; and then proposing this "non-standard for any language" mess to the original asker (who began their question with "I'm very new to C" and did not say "I'm an advanced developer that wants to ruin the simplicity of C with non-standard quirks). Worse; you try to justify this by referencing documentation for an operating system specific file format that has nothing to do with any language.